# Is developing for non-retina iPod Touch/iPhones still worth it for deployment?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, deployment

We're a couple of guys making games for iPod Touch and iPhone. I personally have an iPhone 4 with the retina display and I'll be using this as my main test device. I have an opportunity to purchase a cheap 2nd generation non-retina iPod Touch and was thinking that would be good to have as another test device. But is it worth the purchase?

There is still a huge amount of people on non-retina hand devices? Is a 2nd generation iPod Touch just too old to worry about and maybe I should look into getting a new generation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iPhone 3GS is just as capable as the 4 (armv7, ogles2, latest iOS software) and there are a decent number of them out there. I don't think there's any way to prevent those devices from seeing your game in the store so unless you want the occassional bad review I'd try to support them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

Comment: +1. The main reason to support non-retina is clearly the iPhone 3GS. It's now being sold for cheap (or you get it free) with some mobile-plans. While the older iPods and iPhone 3G stopped at around iOS 4.2.1, the iPhone 3GS can still run the latest iOS version (5.1.1 as of now).

Comment: Yeah I forgot about the iOS version part of it as well.  Added it to my answer.

Comment: @Tetrad So really I should invest my money into getting a iPhone 3GS test machine? I was thinking of getting a newer (yet non-retina) iPod Touch, but that doesn't have the same power as a 3GS? So making tests for non-retina is definitely a good idea it seems, but should I get a newer non-retina iPod Touch or just get the iPhone 3GS for testing?

Comment: From everything I've seen the 3gs is more popular.

Comment: Thanks. After your useful link on the List of IOS devices and your comments here, I do think you're right. I can't really afford not to support the iPhone/iPod Touch 3rd Generation. Thanks!